# WPF, MVVM Populating Cascading ComboBoxes from a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So, I have a UserControl which contains 2 comboboxes, which I want to be filled from a dictionary. So ComboBoxA gets filled with dictionary keys, and ComboBoxB get filled with the dictionary[ComboBoxA selected item]. How can I achieve that using MVVM? Category is basically int, and Parameter is a string.
My code so far:
**Model**

```
public class CategoryUserControlModel
    {
        public Dictionary<Category, List<Parameter>> parametersOfCategories { get; set;}
        public Category chosenCategory { get; set; }
        public Parameter chosenParameter { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CategoryUserControlViewModel
    {

        public CategoryUserControlViewModel(CategoryUserControlModel controlModel)
        {
            Model = controlModel;
        }
        public CategoryUserControlModel Model { get; set; }

        public Category ChosenCategory
        {
            get => Model.chosenCategory;
            set
            {
                Model.chosenCategory = value;
            }
        }

        public Parameter ChosenParameter
        {
            get => Model.chosenParameter;
            set => Model.chosenParameter = value;
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
  <Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Categories" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.parametersOfCategories.Keys}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="0,-2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Категория" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Parameter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.parametersOfCategories.Values}/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ParameterText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="125,-2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Параметр" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using inappropriate names for your model and viewmodel, they should never be related to a view, and your model should not have members with names that give the impression that the model need user interaction. Consider an improved version similar to this one:

```cs
public class CategoryWithParameterModel
{
    public Dictionary<Category, List<Parameter>> ParametersOfCategories { get; set;}
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Parameter Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Your viewmodel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in order to inform the UI that it need to refresh bindings, this is not necessary for model since you are wrapping it in viewmodel. That is said, your viewmodel definition would become something like:

```cs
public class CategoryWithParameterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ... }
```

Next, since you want to bind to a list from the dictionary then your viewmodel have to expose a property which point to that list, let's call it `AvailableParameters`, so it should be defined like this:

```cs
public List<Parameter> AvailableParameters
{
    get
    {
        if (Model.ParametersOfCategories.ContainsKey(ChosenCategory))
            return Model.ParametersOfCategories[ChosenCategory];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

This is the property that need to be bound to `ItemsSource` of second combobox named "Parameter" :)

However, the property `ChosenCategory` is not bound at all so you need to bind it to selected item of first combobox to be able to detect user choice which allow the viemodel to find the list of parameters, same thing applies to `ChosenParameter`, so here is the updated xaml code:

```xml
<Grid>
  <ComboBox x:Name="Categories" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ParametersOfCategories.Keys}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenCategory}"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="0,-2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Категория" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
  <ComboBox x:Name="Parameter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableParameters}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenParameter}"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="ParameterText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="125,-2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Параметр" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
</Grid>
```

Lastly, you have to notify UI when `ChosenCategory` has changed so for this you will need to raise `PropertyChanged` event for `AvailableParameters`. Implementing that will make the viewmodel become something like this:

```cs
public class CategoryWithParameterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CategoryWithParameterViewModel(CategoryWithParameterModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    // This should be read-only
    public CategoryWithParameterModel Model { get; /*set;*/ }

    public Category ChosenCategory
    {
        get => Model.Category;
        set
        {
            Model.Category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AvailableParameters));
        }
    }

    public Parameter ChosenParameter
    {
        get => Model.Parameter;
        set => Model.Parameter = value;
    }

    public List<Parameter> AvailableParameters
    {
        get
        {
            if (Model.ParametersOfCategories.ContainsKey(ChosenCategory))
                return Model.ParametersOfCategories[ChosenCategory];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```